# Twilio access POST data on page .net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, twilio

I am doing my best to try and get a .net webforms twilio app up and running but I am stuck at one part which I haven't found an answer too throughout all the blog posts and tutorials I have read. I have found numerous stack overflow questions but no real answer yet.

Basically: I have an .aspx page that executes: `var call = client.InitiateOutboundCall(options);`,
    which has the `url` set as an ashx page that has:

```
 twiml.BeginGather(new {
 action = "http://sydheller.com/default.aspx",
 numDigits = "1"});
 twiml.Say("Please enter your PIN");
 twiml.Hangup();
```

and then on that default.aspx in the Page_Load I have:

```
 if (Request.Form["Digits"] != null)
 { 
 string digits = Request.Form["Digits"]; 
 digitsLabel.Text = digits; 
 }
```

When I click the button to make the call, I get the call and complete it and it hangs up but nothing happens on my page. I assume I need to use AJAX somehow but I am not sure how to write an ajax request to get information from something that the twilio api/ashx page is posting back.

Does that make sense?

This is driving me crazy and I have a feeling that it is something not particularly complicated that I just don't know and cant figure out.

I would really appreciate any help anyone could throw my way!

Thank you so much in advance,

Syd

Comment: Hey Syd, just to confirm, you are trying to create an application that a user calls and enters a PIN which then appears in a form on the page they are looking at on the website?

Comment: Not exactly, a user goes to a website, clicks "call", the system calls them, they enter a pin, and that pin appears on the site they are looking at